# Should I learn mysqli or PDO?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm pretty much confused. The normal functions such as `mysql_real_escape_string()` will be removed in the future. Therefore, I have been told to learn `mysqli` or `pdo`.

I really don't know which one is prefered, and would like you to tell me which one I should use and why. If possible, Please give me some websites which I can learn everything I need about your choice. I would really like to start using it, as I understood it's safer, and quicker than the normal way.

P.S. I heard something about "prepared statements" and I really struggled to understand what it is, or how it can be used to prevent sql injection. If possible, explain this please.

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli is MYSQL specific, while PDO works interchangeably with other DBMS.

Which one you use is really up to you. Both are capable of similar things. I tend to recommend PDO out of personal preference and flexibility of use, but ultimately, it's up to you.

Comment: Differences are negligible. PDO can be used with multiple DBMS which is the factor which wins it over for myself, at least.

Comment: I see. Is there any source you can give me which I can everything I need about PDO from? P.S. I'm working with MYSQL DB only

Comment: Listen, when you decide to use mysqli then you do everything on your own - php functions serve only as a comunication layer between your script and dbms. This means that you can get everything that MySQL has to offer - you can easily optimize your queries but also you're responsible for every flaws. PDO (like every mapper) takes quite a lot of responsibility from your shoulders. Also, it serves as an abstraction layer so that you don't have to know db specific issues. Advantage is that you can easily switch db but the disadvantage is you sacrifice efficiency sometimes. Choice is up to you.

Comment: @Moby04 Your comment about PDO does not make any sense. The differences between it and MySQLi really only exist on the PHP API side. PDO is **not** a mapper or even an abstraction layer